# Errors with ZXing intergration into Android application

Tags: android, zxing

I have read a few tutorials, but I have problem with integration. I do this sequence:
1) downloading sources;
2) generating core.jar
3) adding as new project folder "android" from sources
4) add core.jar into "android" project

Then I will got many errors - R file doesn't generate, and another mistakes. Where could I make mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can solve that with `organize Imports` - Eclipse.

In fact, this 'problem' is a conflict that happens when you just copy and paste codes..

Try it.

regards

Comment: Sorry, i have just tried to fix it and a lot of problems have fixed, but R file haven't still been making.

Comment: Hm, I've been found this problem, have you tried Repair your project? (Do you use to program in ECLIPSE?)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have copied and pasted our app, in `android/`, into your project. Please do *not* copy and paste our app. Write your own. You do not need any code from our app as it is not a library. You should use `core.jar`, and reuse bits of the Android source if you need to make your app.

Comment: I didn't copy and past, I created a new project with source of code. I need make very simple bar-code scanner, therefore I need execute Intent only. I tried to add core.jar only and I got a exception.

Comment: In your post, you said you tried to add `android/`, as a whole. That's copy and paste. You must have, since it's the only thing with an `R` file. core doesn't have this. Remove `android/` from the project.